# Поиск в списке списков

Tags: python

Неверно работает функция, которая должна находить введенную от 1 до 9 цифру в списке списков и возвращать значение True или False.

```
board = [['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3']]
location = input("select a number (1, 9):" )

def available(location, board):

for row in board:
    if location in row:
        return False
    else:
        return True

available(location, board)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не пойму что не так.

Comment: Вы завершаете выполнение функции на первой же итерации цикла. Т.е. поиск происходит только в `['7', '8', '9']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы выходите на первой итерации.

```
def available(location, board):
  """ Проверяет наличие location в board """
  for row in board:
    if location in row:
      return True
  return False
def available2(location, board):
  """ Проверяет отсутствие location в board """
  for row in board:
    if location in row:
      return False
  return True
def available_flat(location, board):
  """ Проверяет наличие location в board, разворачивая список в плоский """
  return location in [item for sub in board for item in sub]


board = [['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3']]
location = input("select a number (1, 9):" )
available(location, board)
```